# How to get rid of System.ObjectDisposedException when showing a form for the second time?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a form with a full picture which helps players to see where to move their puzzles in the game. When I show it for the second time, after I closed it, System.ObjectDisposedException is thrown.

I tried to use Hide() method when FormClosed event happened but it did not help. Also, I deleted the pictureBox from the control because I thought that it was causing this exception but is did not help either.

```
Original_px OrPix = new Original_px();

        private void showFullPictureToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OrPix.Show();
        }
```

I want this form to work without this exception

Comment: Without seeing more code there is no way to solve your problem. This message is telling you that you are trying to reference an object that has already been disposed.

Comment: This: `Original_px OrPix = new Original_px();` is the mistake. `new` a Form each time you close it. After you have closed that Form, your `OrPix` object is not valid anymore (it's `disposed`). Change in `Original_px OrPix = null;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close the form, through the close upper right icon or through code calling the form Close() method then the variable *OrPix* will reference a closed and disposed object. 
You cannot reuse it without reinitilizing the variable with *new Original_px();*.

You need to know when the form is closed and you can receive this information handling the FormClosed event and set that variable to null.
So, when you need to display it again (or for the first time) you should check to see if the variable is null and reinitialize it

```
Original_px OrPix = null;

private void showFullPictureToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(OrPix == null)
    {
       OrPix = new Original_px();
       OrPix.FormClosed += PixClosed;
    }
    OrPix.Show();
}

private void PixClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    OrPix = null;
}
```